# subir dados de um arquivo excel no banco de dados usando api

Tags: react, flask

estou construindo uma api usando flask restx, nao sei se minha ideia e possivel, porem queria poder ter uma maneira do usuario conseguir subir um arquivo excel no banco de dados, cada excel se trasnforma em uma tabela no banco de dados, porem react js em relação a back end, funciona apenas com api, e nao sei como usar a api para fazer tal efeito

```
from flask_restx import Resource, Namespace

@ns.route('/registo_tabela') class etapas_aprovacao(Resource): 

method_decorators = [jwt_required()] @ns.doc(security="jsonWebToken")
@ns.expect(etapas_aprovacao_model, validate=True)
@ns.marshal_list_with(etapas_aprovacao_model)
def post(self):
    if execelFile:
        df  = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(excelFile))

    for index, row in df.iterrows
    # Criar uma nova instância de EtapasAprovacoes a partir dos dados da solicitação
    new_etapa_aprovacao = EtapasAprovacoes(
        nome_subtabela=request.json['nome_subtabela'],
        usuario_id=request.json['usuario_id'],
        departamento_id=request.json['departamento_id'],
        etapa_id=request.json['etapa_id'],
        status_aprovacao='pendente',
        data_aprovacao= None ,
        created_at=datetime.utcnow()
    )

    db.session.add(new_etapa_aprovacao)
    db.session.commit()
    setExcelFile(None)

    return new_etapa_aprovacao
```